# Best way to save custom css for an block

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm building a custom "row" plugin and would like to control some css-grid related stuff from the backend. What is the "best way" to save the css generated from the controls and how to inject it into the website?

Right now I'm using `add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'render_server_side_css' ) );`, to get my css stored inside block attributesto the frontend (head), but is this js + php approach the best way or is there a more "gutenberg ready" approach to solve this issue?

And if that is the right way, how to generate some ids for styling? The client id is always changing, so that is not really an option ...

Comment: have you looked into global styles? Is your block a user CSS block? Generally the concept is that you wouldn't need user written CSS to style an individual block, global styles or the blocks attributes would do that with a GUI instead. There's also the html class and ID attributes on blocks that are in the advanced panel of the block sidebar

Comment: @TomJNowell The user generates CSS via the input controls and everything is stored inside some attributes. But what is the proper way to get this css displayed in the frontend?

Comment: if the user is using input controls why does custom CSS need to be generated? Is using html utility classes such as `my_div--bold my_div--emphasised my_div--big-rounded-corners` etc? Similar to how image alignment generates classes and data attributes that can be styled in the image blocks. Generating raw CSS that then needs to be loaded is somewhat of an anti-pattern to be avoided. My inclination is to put it inline, a wp_head hook means i need to know all the blocks that could be displayed, which falls apart utterly when we introduce widget areas/block templates/full site editing etc

Comment: however, to actually answer your question in a satisfying way more information is necessary about your context. The canonical answer to your question as you asked it is: _"it depends"_. What kind of controls? What is the code you're currently using to implement this?

Comment: The problem with inline css is that i need media queries, so that doesn't work. And I would like to control things like grid gap or other specific things. Not really possible with classes ...

Comment: By inline CSS I meant a `<style>` tag, not a `style=""` attribute. You can significantly minimise how much custom CSS is needed with utility classes, unless you're trying to use absolute positioning which I would advise against, but even then you would only need the one rule to define the offset. As I said though, the correct answer depends on the context